# how can i resolve unable located pgk for conky in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: command-line, conky, 19.10

```
kyawzinxtet@ga:~$ sudo apt-get install conky-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package conky-manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conky-manager` [is not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=conky-manager) in the official repositories of all supported Ubuntu versions (including 19.10).

You can try to find PPA with this package on the [corresponding LaunchPad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=conky-manager) and/or request building of it for Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) on PPA page.

---

Update 20191103: *tomtomtom* released [Conky Manager package](https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager) for 19.10.

Comment: Thank you so much @N0bert

Comment: @KyawZin *tomtomtom* have released conky-manager package for *eoan*.